# Menu block plugin like functionality

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-views, drupal-blocks

I've installed the "Menu block" module, and it is doing a great job in creating levels 2+ menus inside pages. However, I want to know whether I can imitate a similar functionality. In first level menu pages I want to create large boxes that contain links to the children of that page. Basically, the same functionality that the plugin provides except that a different layout. I have tried using the Views plugin and creating it as a box but I find no way whatsoever to specify as a filter that only the children of the current menu link should be displayed. Could you help me to implement such a functionality? What kind of modules, options should I use?

Comment: Pls show a working example or a picture for me to have a look . Maybe then I can suggest a solution

Comment: Please check this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fnLmD.png

Answer (score 1):

Based on your layout I suggest you create a view as a block and then filter the results based on a taxanomy term and them limit the number.

In the end you should have four blocks with 4 different taxonomy terms as filters.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was thinking too, but unfortunately I am not using taxonomy in this project. I'm rather going with the 'menu' approach.

Comment: I don't think views can help you then. Filter criteria in views is good for tags, taxonomy ..   If you want only based on menu then you will need to make a module for that.